# create text box in ppt using VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I want to create a text box in Power Point via VBA excel, this is my code :

```
   Set Sh = PptDoc.Shapes.AddLabel(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
       Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=150, Height:=60)
    Sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Worksheets("Source").Range("D14")
    Sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 100, 255)
```

But when I am running, it say there is a problem with Activ X ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working properly if `Pptdoc` is already defined as PowerPoint slide like the example below

```
Dim pp As PowerPoint.Application, pptdoc As Slide, pptLayout As CustomLayout
Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pp.Visible = True

'If you are creating a new Presentation and New slide the
pp.Presentations.Add
Set pptLayout = pp.ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
Set pptdoc = pp.ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(1, pptLayout)

'If you are using an existing presentation then delete above 3 lines use the 2 lines below
'pp.Presentations.Open ("C:\users\User\desktop\test.pptm")
'Set pptdoc = pp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Set Sh = pptdoc.Shapes.AddLabel(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
       Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=150, Height:=60)
    Sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Worksheets("Source").Range("D14").Value
    Sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 100, 255)
```

Also always try  add Microsoft PowerPoint Object library in the tools-references while working with PowerPoint. It is always safe to use `.Value` with excel ranges when you intent to write values only.